# Laravel, Vue.js | blank pdf getting downloaded via axios request

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, dompdf

I've been trying to download a PDF from my Laravel application via axios, but the file that's getting downloaded is an empty pdf.

I am using DomPdf to create pdf and download.js to download it below is my code.

Note:: **it works just fine if I try to download it without ajax request.**

Laravel,

`return PDF::loadView('print', compact('bill'))->download($bill->number.'.pdf');`
Javascript

```
``axios.get(`/bills/${id}/print` {
responseType: 'blob',Accept: 'application/pdf'
})
.then(response => {
  const download = require('@/download');
  // @ is just an alias for my root js directory.
  download(response.data, `file.pdf`, 'application/pdf');
});``
```

Comment: Have you used browser tools to ensure that you're getting back the PDF from your GET request? If you set a breakpoint in your browser dev tools do you see the PDF content in `response.data`?

Comment: oddly the problem had something to do with axios I found it randomly on stackoverflow. And ended up using one of it's answer which suggested using xlhttprequest, it worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try following code:

In Laravel controller:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('finance.remainingFee', compact('fee', 'time'));
$pdf->setPaper('a4' , 'portrait');
return $pdf->output();
```

And in Vue file:

```
  axios.get(APP_URL + `api/finance/remainingStudentFee/${fee_id}`, {responseType: 'blob'}).then(response => {

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'remaining_fee.pdf'); //or any other extension
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```